# Почему в калькуляторе цифры не записываются продолжительно?

Tags: c#

Создаю калькулятор. Но тут встретил такую проблему: Нажимаю на кнопки с цифрами и при этом цифра(одна) высвечивается в TextBox, но при нажатии на другую кнопку, прежняя удаляется и вместо него высвечивается новая (одна). Впервые сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. В чем дело???

Вот код:

```
private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "1";
}

private void button24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "2";
}
```

Comment: button24 button25 это сильно (причем код один и тот же)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы **заменяете** содержимое `TextBox`'а

```
private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "1";
}

private void button24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "2";
}
```

Comment: Не `&`, а `+`.

Comment: Не знаком с этим вашим бейсиком-с-фигурными-скобками, но прав AlexeyM, и случится конкатенация, а не сложение. `String` же!

Comment: @niki-timofe Как вы вообще додумались использовать здесь '&'? Расскажите, пожалуйста, ход ваших мыслей, очень интересно.

Comment: самое странное - почему этот ответ принят?

Comment: Потому, что ответ ответ единственный и содержит хинт, от которого ОПу полегчало (что бы эта продолжительная запись цифр не означала).

Comment: Извиняюсь, поленился открыть `Visual Studio`, да, **на самом деле `+`**

------

@Котик, руководствовался тем, что в `Visual Basic.NET` **сложение** переменных типа `string` даёт результат **суммы их значений** (*конечно, если они не символьные и не буквенные*), а не две строки сложенных в одну, как в других *ЯП*

*Т. е. в `VB.NET` знак `&` может означать как конъюнкцию, так и сложение двух строк в одну.*

Comment: @niki-timofe

- То, что вы сказали насчет операции сложения, применимой к типам `String` в `VB` - это [неправда.][1] В `VB` `"abc" + "def" -> "abcdef".` Ну и это ни разу не оправдывает факт влепления `VB` кода при ответе на вопрос по `C#` :)

- *(Оффтоп)* Использование `operator &` для *строгой* конкантенации строчек - это, кстати, очень странное языковое решение. Лично я не очень понимаю, зачем на `operator +` было возлагать настолько сложную логику, чтобы пришлось вводить дополнительный `strict` оператор для конкантенации строчек.

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/te2585xw

Comment: > *Из всего сказанного следует, что смешивать `C#` и `VB .NET` - плохо, как мне, так и их создателю* **(`MS`)**

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, это не введение, а возврат к традиционному для Бейсика оператору конкатенации.

Comment: @karmadro4 Да, согласен. Правда в таком случае все еще интересен вопрос, зачем было вешать на `operator +` кучу дополнительной логики с неявными преобразованиями типов.

> The + operator has a complex set of rules that determine whether to add, concatenate, signal a compiler error, or throw a run-time InvalidCastException exception.

Comment: @Котикхочеткушать, полагаю, что опять же наследие безтипового прошлого. Язык BASIC, его пользователи are basic too, but rules are complex. Прямо шкатулка Пандоры получается.

Comment: @karmadro4, Цитата препода по программированию:

 > *VB - язык для домохозяек*